# opencv brg color histogram not work

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, histogram

I am reading OpenCV 2 Computer Vision Application Programming Cookbook and implementing examples in it.

In chapter 4, color histogram example doesn't work unfortunately.

The code is below. But this code does not give me histogram or any error. Also, it says that color images histogram is three dimensional. I don't understand why it is thee and it is not two.

```
    #include <opencv2\imgproc\imgproc.hpp>
    #include <opencv2\highgui\highgui.hpp>
    #include <opencv2\core\core.hpp>
    #include <iostream>

    using namespace cv;
    using namespace std;

    int main(){
        Mat image = imread("waves.jpg");
        int histSize[3];
        float hranges[2];
        const float* ranges[3];
        int channels[3];
        // Prepare arguments for a color histogram
        histSize[0] = histSize[1] = histSize[2] = 256;
        hranges[0] = 0.0; // BRG range
        hranges[1] = 255.0;
        ranges[0] = hranges; // all channels have the same range
        ranges[1] = hranges;
        ranges[2] = hranges;
        channels[0] = 0; // the three channels
        channels[1] = 1;
        channels[2] = 2;

        Mat hist;
        // Compute histogram
        calcHist(&image,
            1, // histogram of 1 image only
            channels, // the channel used
            cv::Mat(), // no mask is used
            hist, // the resulting histogram
            3, // it is a 3D histogram
            histSize, // number of bins
            ranges // pixel value range
            );

        cout << hist.at<int>(100, 100, 0) << endl;
        cout << hist.at<int>(100, 100, 1) << endl;
        cout << hist.at<int>(100, 100, 2) << endl;

        return 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. This code above **DOES** give you a 3D histogram. I don't quite understand why you think it does not.
2. Why is it three-dimensional? Because argument `int dim` in method calcHist() has value **3**. If you want 2D histogram then it would be **2**.
3. You want to print values of 3D histogram with `cout << hist.at<int>(x, y, z) << endl;` where x, y and z are coordinates for 3D histogram.

Comment: Unfortunately it does not give me 3d histogram. This is my problem. After calcHist function, dim is equal 3 but row and col is equal -1. cout prints just zeros to the screen. Debugging I obtain the following relevant info from the 3Dhistrogram matrix:

Dimensions: 3, Rows: -1, Columns: -1, Size: 256

Comment: Please, look [here](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#mat) . For cols and rows it says _"the number of rows and columns or (-1, -1) when the array has more than 2 dimensions"_ . And for your zeros, it is because there is no color in image for that element. Try to print a full histogram using iterator like this:
`for (MatConstIterator_<int> it = hist.begin<int>(); it != hist.end<int>(); it++) {
  cout << *it << " ";
 }` and I'm pretty sure it will print some values for some elements. Simply note that your 3D histogram with range 256 will have 16777216 elements.

Comment: thanks for your help.  It gives me only crazy numbers over 1 billion at some elements 3d matrix. most of the 3d matrix just zeros. Actually i don't understand why book gives like that example. What is the meaning of 256x256x256 array?

Comment: I found the reason of crazy numbers. I used at<int> template function but it was not correct. Printing numbers using at<float> gives correct output. Also I realized why we use 256x256x256 3d matrix. [A Guide to Utilizing Color Histograms for Computer Vision and Image Search Engines](http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2014/01/22/clever-girl-a-guide-to-utilizing-color-histograms-for-computer-vision-and-image-search-engines/)